# Connect to multiple databases with user/pass file(s) and import data

Tags: linux, mysql, bash, import

Good day,
I have about 30 empty databases all on the same host. I am trying to write a script to import all the database schemas and data, that have already been exported using mysqldump in the correct format from another host.

Something in the format of:
MYSQL_USER=`for users in 'cat db_users.txt';done`
MYSQL_PASS=`for pass in 'cat db_pass.txt';done`
DBNAME=`for dbs in 'cat db_name.txt';done`
DBSCHEMAFILES=`ls *.schema.sql`
DBDATAFILES=`ls *.data.sql`

do mysql -h mydbhost -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS $DBNAME < $DBSCHEMAFILES;done

do mysql -h mydbhost -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS $DBNAME < $DBDATAFILES;done

The above is just the idea and in no way working.
Thank you in advance.

MySQL ver: mysql  Ver 8.0.26

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop for that. If you dump ALL of the databases and restore them all on another host, all you need is the mysqldump command.

This is VERRY WELL documented from MySQL (Oracle).

Check for mysqldump ''--all-databases'' in the mysqldump documentation
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

As for the users and access, it should also be documented. I think you can dump and restore mysql schema for that.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. Maybe I should have mentioned that the source DB is a GCP MySQL DB and the destination DB Server is planetscale MySQL.
Sorry should have been more specific.
The destination db server has all the databases but each database has its own username and password so importing will not work from a mysqldump. Each database has been exported into two seperate files for each database. One xyz.schema.sql and one xyz.data.sql

I got it working with the following, using a .csv file with the dbname,host,user,pass columns:

while IFS="," read -r dbname host user pass; do
mysql -h "$host" -u "$user" -p"$pass" $dbname < "$dbname.data.sql"
done < secrets.csv

Hope it helps someone when migrating to planetscale.

D

Answer (score 0):

30 copies of the same data?  If so,

- Load the one copy in.
- Tell `mysqldump` not to "create the database"; instead simply populate it.
- Use that one dump 30 times, each time do your own `CREATE DATABASE` and tell `mysql` to load the dump into that database.

If 30 different databases, please clarify the question.